# Can't find the index number of an htmlCollection that has a particular class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make 'progress' dynamic breadcrumbs, that have different styles before and after the current page. So I began with a bootstrap list group that I with some exra php to make the class of 'active' dynamic depending on which page was loaded as a server-side include:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
  <li class="bread list-group-item.active"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
  <li class="bread list-group-item"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <ul>
```

Then I  did...

```
var myHtmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('bread');
console.log(myHtmlCollection);
```

Gives...

HTMLCollection(2) [li.bread.list-group-item.active, li.bread.list-group-item]

... So this is an HTMLCollection (because I'd read that these are updated by the DOM when something changes, whereas a NodeList wouldn't change when the 'active' class shifted.

Then I decided that i'd need to know the index number of the current page, so I decided to convert the HTMLCollection to an array:

```
var myArray = Array.from(myHtmlCollection);
console.log(myArray);
```

Gives...

(2) [li.list-group-item.active, li.list-group-item.]

Now I've been focusing mainly on the using the built-in findIndex() function. So this code...

```
myArray.findIndex(myFunction);

function myFunction(i){
   console.log(i);
}
```

This gives me the following

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHc8S.png)

Now I'm stumped. Is this the wrong approach? I've tried to do some pattern-matching, but nothing working. Please help!

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? Do you want to find the index of an element with specified text? Or with a specified class? Or something else? This would allow us to not only tell you what is wrong but also tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been clearer. So how would I return the index number of the element with the active class. Everything I’ve tried returned -1.

Comment: My intention is to use the current position (I.e. index) to adjust styles in the original HTML Dom.

Comment: I will edit my answer for your solution.

Comment: I think it’s about checking whether the array has a certain value, but the ‘.active’ class is amongst a lot of other stuff. Is some sort of pattern matching the only way?

Comment: Did you see my updated answer on using `classList.contains`? You may have to refresh your page to see the changes.

Comment: Cool. That looks sound. Had to walk dog. I’ll check it out. Just wondering whether classList works on normal arrays rather DOM elements, because I converted it for the purposes of using findIndex method for arrays

Comment: ClassList only work on DOM elements, though from the screenshot you provided the array is made up of DOM elements. To check if an array of [classNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) has a class I would use something like `array.filter(v=>v.includes(".active"))`

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

> The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function

`myFunction` is run on all elements of the array until `true` is returned. Therefore, it is logging all elements because true is never returned.

You can solve this by changing `myFunction` to

```
function myFunction(i){
   return i.classList.contains("active");
}
```

Read about `.classList.contains` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains).

Answer (score 0):

This code returned the index position from my HTMLCollection.

So imagine these are breadcrumbs...

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
<li class="bread list-group-item"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li class="bread list-group-item"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li class="bread list-group-item.active"><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
</ul> 


<script>

var myHtmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('bread');

// loop through the HTMLCollection and push each value into an empty array which we'll call 'list'...

var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myHtmlCollection.length; i++) {
   list.push(myHtmlCollection[i].className)
}

console.log(list.indexOf("bread list-group-item active")); // e.g. 2

</script>
```

And when the 'active' class changes to a different breadcrumb dynamically via some PHP, the index number changes dynamically as well.